# How to create a comparison table using console outputs from two different methods

Tags: java, compare

I have created a methods that reads two `xml` files then compare them and output the result in the console.

I want to be able to change the console output and create a table to clearly show the difference between the files. To make the output more readable since we are comparing.

I have a method that takes two arguments that is called in the main class:

```
compareValues(file1, file2);
compareValues(file2, file1);
```

The method is called twice so that file1 is compared to file2 & file2 is compared to file1. that way any changes in both file will be noticed.
So the output should look like the following example:

The Result I want to achieve is:

```
xmlTable1  --> xmlTable2
val = 2    -->  val = 3
time = 17:00 --> time = 15:00
```

How can I manipulate the console output to produce a table?

Comment: what's your problem?

Comment: The problem is that i am getting duplicated output since I run the methods twice and I am not about to structure a table from the result.

Comment: Then change your method so that it compares both files and outputs only once. We can't help you do that at this point since we have no idea how your method is written, please include your method code if you would like help with it.

Comment: Comparing files is not simple. I suggest you to look on some existing algorithms.